# Odd URI from samsung keyboard for gifs

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I am using an [OnReceiveContentListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/view/OnReceiveContentListener) to get gifs from the android soft keyboard. Everything works fine except samsung keyboards seem to give back a uri that I don't know how to handle. For example, I got this uri back

content://com.samsung.android.honeyboard.provider/root/data/data/com.samsung.android.honeyboard/temp_content/com.samsung.android.icecone.gif/ef9caa2d-58ca-4b07-9016-4910dae32436.gif

Does anyone know what to do with this to turn it into a proper link? A url to somewhere like giphy would be ideal.

Comment: You get a nice uri, a nice content scheme, for a gif. What is the problem,?

Comment: And what kind of link did you want? Example please.